# How to show Exceptions custom message on Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using messages to show success, info and warning message from Django classed based views to Django template.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    try:
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message % obj.__dict__)
        return super(CurrencyDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except ProtectedError:
        messages.error(self.request, "can't delete this category")
```

Now I am confused how to show that ProtectedError message on the template and what to return after that message.error.

Comment: is APIView your class?

Comment: My class is CurrencyDeleteView

Comment: instead of  `return super(CurrencyDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)`
try `render(request,"template.html",{"meassage":"some message"})` you can show message in django template. try same in `ProtectedError` block

Comment: thanks for reply. I can use this method but can you have a solution with using generic things without using render

Comment: I need to look in docs what is super class of CurrencyDeleteView? you can consider adding a method like `get_error_url` to class

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it.

Comment: If you can post your answer someone may get help by it

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('settings:category_list')

def get_error_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('settings:category_list')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['active_menu'] = {"menu1":"setting","menu2":"category","menu3":"basic","menu4":"category"}
    return context

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    get_success_url = self.get_success_url()
    get_error_url = self.get_error_url()
    try:
        obj.delete()
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message % obj.__dict__)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(get_success_url)
    except ProtectedError:
        messages.warning(self.request, self.protected_error % obj.__dict__)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(get_error_url)
```

Answering my own question so someone get help for same problem.